# Indirect/Direct speech, Is/was: Another thing I wanted to ask is to whom I should submit

Tags: word-order, indirect-question

I am completely at a loss here. 
I know it's the basics, but do I say:

> Another thing I wanted to ask is to whom *I should* submit the paper

or

> Another thing I wanted to ask is to whom *should I* submit the paper

and that with or without a comma?

I would not use "was" because it doesn't sound natural to me, since I am supposed to send the document now, but please give your opinion on that as well. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I think that any of the forms you suggest are fine. It's a matter of preference and style rather than any single form being grammatical while the others are not.